# RegExp not working as expected capturing strings within parens

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a problem where I get a string that has several sets of parenthesis in it.

ex. "(024,025,026,027,028),(029,030,031,032,033)"

At the time I get the string I have a variable holding a string say "030".   I create a regular expression as such:

`var re = new RegExp(".*?\\((.*?" + id + ".*?)\\).*");`

and do a replace as follows:

`string.replace(re, "$1");`

So the problem is that if the number falls within the first set of parenthesis then it will work properly but if it falls within the second it will not.

so:

```
var id = "024";   
var re = new RegExp(".*?\\((.*?" + id + ".*?)\\).*");
var string = "(024,025,026,027,028),(029,030,031,032,033)";
document.writeln(string.replace(re, "$1"));
```

Returns "024,025,026,027,028"

but:

```
var id = "029";   
var re = new RegExp(".*?\\((.*?" + id + ".*?)\\).*");
var string = "(024,025,026,027,028),(029,030,031,032,033)";
document.writeln(string.replace(re, "$1"));
```

Returns: "024,025,026,027,028),(029,030,031,032,033"

I am specifying the `?` to minimize what is captured between the parens - but it does not seem to work.   Can someone explain what I am missing?

Here is a JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/rdwAP/#&togetherjs=xVQ7Ltd8rO

Comment: Replace `.*?` with `[^()]*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to extract data from a string, it's usually a good idea

- to avoid vague, catch-all, or negated patterns
- to use `match` instead of `replace`

It's cleaner, more explicit, and faster.

Here you should use `(\d+,)*` and `(,\d+)*` instead of just `.*?`.

```js
var id = "029";   
var re = new RegExp("\\(((\\d+,)*" + id + "(,\\d+)*)\\)");
var string = "(024,025,026,027,028),(029,030,031,032,033)";
document.writeln(string.match(re)[1]);
```

Note that this explicit regex will also fail in case of garbage input, which is generally considered a plus.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.*?` in your regex, use negated pattern instead:

```
var id = "029";   
var re = new RegExp("\\(([^)]*" + id + "[^)]*)\\)");
var string = "(024,025,026,027,028),(029,030,031,032,033)";
string.replace(re, "$1");
//=> "(024,025,026,027,028),029,030,031,032,033"
```

- `([^)]*` will match 0 or more of any character that is not `)` thus stoping your match when it gets `)`.
- Whereas when you have `.*?` it will match until it finds `id` variable which exists in 2nd set of `(...)`.